# Weird Error: Hit ENTER key in listbox, get NULL error for bound recordset values

Tags: vba, listbox, null, ms-access-2007, recordset

Access 2007 ADP/ADE.

I have a modal that is bound to a table. The modal has a single listbox control, and two buttons. One executes a subroutine of code that access values from the bound recordset, the other closes the modal.

Two methods of use:

1. Select a value in the listbox, and then click on the button to execute the subroutine, it works just fine.
2. Select a value in the listbox and then hit the ENTER
   key on the keyboard twice, it attempts to execute the same
   subroutine, but throws a NULL error the first time it tries to
   access a value from the bound record.

So using method 1, a value like Me.RecordNumber will return 12345. Using Method 2, it will be NULL and error out. Interestingly enough, the selected value in the listbox itself is available using either method.

Not really a critical bug, but it is annoying. I have to teach folks to click buttons rather than just use the ENTER key on this particular modal. Has anyone seen this before? Any idea why values from a bound recordset are unavailable using method #2?

**EDIT for clarification:**
This error appears to be independent of any particular piece of VBA code. I've even created a new modal, bound a different table, and just tried to access a random datacolumn on that recordset. Same result.

Here is the snippet where the error appears. It errors out when attempting to grab the RecordType, a value that is never null.

```
Private Sub cmdAddFromTemplate_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_MyErrorHandler

Dim myTemplateName As String
Dim myDepartment As String  

Dim i As Integer

'Did they provide a valid template name?
If Me.listTemplateToImport.ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then

    'Cycle through list and build criteria
    For i = 0 To Me.listTemplateToImport.ListCount - 1

        'Is this status selected?
        If Me.listTemplateToImport.Selected(i) Then

            'Grab selected template name
            myTemplateName = Trim(Me.listTemplateToImport.ItemData(i))

        End If

    Next i

Else

    'Warn and exit
    MsgBox "You must select a valid template name.", vbOKOnly, "STEP: Action Canceled"

    Exit Sub

End If

'Grab Bound Values
myDepartment = Me.RecordType 'NULL error here when using ENTER key.
```

Comment: What's the code behind those events ?

Comment: This is an ADP. The back end is a MS SQL 2005 DB. Also, as stated above, I've created a new modal, bound a different table, and just tried to access a random datacolumn on that recordset. Same result. I think this may be some bizarre behavior in Access, rather than project specific issue.